# How to get total discount amount of Coupon Code for all items in the cart

Tags: cart, ce-1.9.0.1, discount, coupon

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and here is the code on which I am working on:

```
$quote2 = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach ($quote2->getAllItems() as $item){
    $DiscountTotal = $item->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

This code is giving me the amount discounted with coupon code of the first item in the cart for the current session.

The problem is that this code is giving me the amount discounted only for the first item but not for all items in the cart for the current session.

So I have two questions:

1. How I can get the total discount amount for all items the cart for the current session?
2. How I can get the total discount amount for already completed order?

Comment: what you mean by lready completed order

Comment: I mean when the order is finished, how i can get the amount in the order view page in the admin panel for example. It is more important for me to know the answer for the first question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$quote2 = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$discountTotal = 0;
foreach ($quote2->getAllItems() as $item){
    $discountTotal += $item->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Magento saves each item respective discount on `sales_flat_quote_item` table at column `discount_amount`. This Discount Amount is stored  in`current currency`.

**For getting total discount of current  session, try the below code**

```
$totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
$totalDiscount = $totals["discount"]->getValue();
```

**For getting the current order discount amount at order view, try the below code**

```
$OrderObject->getDiscountAmount();
```